# Parent Child Chain Query

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I have a database of California Rivers. Every river has an ID and a ParentID. These are the only two columns. The ID represents the Child(river receiving water from the Parent), and the ParentID represents the Parent(river supplying the child with water).

The ParentID of a Child is the ID of that particular Parent; thus, an ID of a Parent appears in both columns. When there is no Parent to a river, the ParentID = 0. This makes it the first river in a long chain of rivers.

I am trying to create a query that gives me this chain of rivers.

EDIT: I am not able to run CTE Recursive queries with the version MySQL 5.7, and I am looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: "they are rivers"... what do you mean? It's not a term I've heard previously to describe database columns

Comment: anyway it sounds like you probably need some kind of recursive function if you want to traverse your entire tree (because that's effectively the kind of structure you've created, I think), not sure it's something you can do easily with SQL...maybe with functions/procedures, perhaps I guess

Comment: I have edited post and it seems like recursive is definitely possible, but I am still having trouble creating code that works. I get a syntax error when attempting to execute.

Comment: you'd better tell us precisely what error you get

Comment: In addition to the below error response, there is a red line under "WITH" that reads on hover: ' "WITH" is not valid at this position for this server position, expecting: EOF, BEGIN, CACHE, CHECKSUM... ' 

The error response:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte AS (    Select Parent where Child = 'Clear Creek-Sacramento River'     UNION' at line 1

Comment: What version of mysql do you have?

Comment: I ask that because CTEs were only added to MySQL in version 8

Comment: I am using version 8

Comment: ok well the code you've posted won't, by itself, result in the reported syntax error as far as I can see. Are you using this in the middle of some other code? Try to test it in isolation first

Comment: more specifically 8.0.12

Comment: It seems to be an issue with my MySQL rather than the code, when runnning this simple example, I receive the same error: 

 WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT * FROM cte;

Comment: Hm, sounds a bit weird. Try running it in a sandbox like https://dbfiddle.uk/ to check if the actual code is correct (you can run CREATE, INSERT statements etc to create a few tables and data to enable a test)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5bca80208b4f996ff82ff31865f25b0f runs your simple example happily (since it requires no extra tables).

Comment: yes, I can run it on a standard SQL db as well, but unfortunately need it for MySQL Workbench v 8.0.12........ I will start a new post aimed at this issue

Comment: Workbench is just a client application which can talk to MySQL, it is not the server. The version of Workbench is irrelevant as to whether CTEs are supported. The SQL code is parsed and executed by the server, not the client. The client just sends the code to the server, and waits for the result. You need to check the version of the server you're connecting to. Execute `SELECT VERSION()` to find out

Comment: This was the issue. i am running Workbench 8, but MySql 5.7... thank you for clarification, post will be edited here